# Calculate total amount of time spent on website group by UNIQUE ID

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

What I have is couple of user id's and there time seen every one hour . I want to calculate sum of time spent by each user (uptime) but excluding every data point that is late by 60 minutes that means avoid any timestamp which is more than 120 minutes than previous one. and group by finally on one day extracted from timestamp itself. I also take the connection frequency by calling it disconnect in case a gap of more than 2 or more hour is seen in data and increment the count by 1. This makes the connection frequency. Remember that query is written for BigQuery.

1. time gap between 120 minutes to 1440 minutes ( 2 hours to 24 hours is considered as gap between data and must be ignored from sum of time spend calculations but connection times should be incremented by 1 because it will be considered as disconnect)

```
    unique_id         server_time
    50J181700696    2019-07-02 00:14:14.157 UTC
    50J181700696    2019-07-02 01:14:14.136 UTC
    50J181700696    2019-07-02 02:14:14.116 UTC
    50J181700696    2019-07-02 04:14:14.065 UTC
    50J181700696    2019-07-02 05:14:14.041 UTC
    50J181700696    2019-07-02 07:14:13.987 UTC
    50J181700696    2019-07-02 08:14:13.961 UTC
    50J181700696    2019-07-02 11:14:13.873 UTC
    50J181700696    2019-07-02 12:14:13.852 UTC
    50J181700696    2019-07-02 13:14:13.822 UTC
```

```sql
    SELECT
      date_column,
      unique_id,
      SUM(
      case TIMESTAMP_DIFF(prev_server_time,server_time,minute) between 0 and 120
            when server_time is null or prev_server_time is null then 0
            when server_time > prev_server_time then TIMESTAMP_DIFF(server_time,prev_server_time,minute)
            else 0 
           END
      ) AS uptime_per_day,
      SUM(
      case not (TIMESTAMP_DIFF(prev_server_time,server_time,minute) between 0 and 120 )
            when prev_server_time is null or server_time is null then 0
            when server_time > prev_server_time and TIMESTAMP_DIFF(server_time,prev_server_time,minute) between 120 and 1440 then 1
            else 0 
           END
      ) AS connection_times
    FROM (
      SELECT
        date_column,
        unique_id,
        server_time,
        LAG(server_time ) OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id ORDER BY date_column   ) AS prev_server_time
      FROM (
        SELECT
          unique_id,
          server_time,
          DATE(server_time) AS date_column
        FROM
          `table_user_entry`
        ))
    GROUP BY
      date_column,
      unique_id
```

```
date_column unique_id      uptime_per_day(minutes) connection_times
2019-07-02  50J181700696      420                       3
```

Comment: Explain why your query doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Well its not well written for start, but main problem that I think is lag function used to create a column of timestamp is not working correctly and that is why the final sum that I get is not correct

Comment: I also wanted to try one of the join based solutions for creating a column joined on itself but that didnt work either because the ID are not numeric which I can iterate over or increment to get next in column

Answer (score 0):

These are the results I got when I ran your query:

[image: Results using OP original sql]

The uptime_per_day is 0 because `TIMESTAMP_DIFF(prev_server_time,server_time,minute) between 0 and 120` will always be False, since the timestamp diff will always be negative. You have to swap the order of the server times to have a positive value: `TIMESTAMP_DIFF(server_time,prev_server_time,minute)`

When using the LAG function `LAG(server_time ) OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id ORDER BY date_column   ) AS prev_server_time` order the data by server_time instead of date_column. This will guarantee that you are indeed comparing with the previous row, and you won't need to do validations like `server_time > prev_server_time`

Here's a query without the aggregation to see how is calculating the times.

```sql
SELECT
      date_column,
      unique_id,
      IF(time_diff between 0 and 120, time_diff, 0) as up_time,
      IF(time_diff IS NULL OR time_diff between 120 and 1440, 1, 0) as connection_started

    FROM (
      SELECT
        DATE(server_time) as date_column,
        unique_id,
        server_time,
        prev_server_time,
        TIMESTAMP_DIFF(server_time,prev_server_time,minute) AS time_diff
      FROM (
        SELECT
          unique_id,
          server_time,
          LAG(server_time ) OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id ORDER BY server_time ) AS prev_server_time
        FROM
          `table_user_entry`
        ))
```

[image: Results]

And the final results with the aggregations.

```sql
WITH connection_data as (SELECT
      date_column,
      unique_id,
      IF(time_diff between 0 and 120, time_diff, 0) as uptime,
      IF(time_diff IS NULL OR time_diff between 120 and 1440, 1, 0) as connection_started

    FROM (
      SELECT
        DATE(server_time) as date_column,
        unique_id,
        server_time,
        prev_server_time,
        TIMESTAMP_DIFF(server_time,prev_server_time,minute) AS time_diff
      FROM (
        SELECT
          unique_id,
          server_time,
          LAG(server_time ) OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id ORDER BY server_time ) AS prev_server_time
        FROM
          `table_user_entry`
        ))
)
SELECT date_column, unique_id, SUM(uptime) as uptime, SUM(connection_started) as connection_times
    FROM connection_data
    GROUP BY date_column, unique_id
```

[image: Aggregated results]

These results might be different from what you expected. Note that when there are 120 minutes of difference between the server times, those differences are strictly smaller than 120 minutes, so you may need to adjust it depending on your complete work scenario.